# Which lines in awk source code apply an operator (`++`) to an expression?

Tags: awk, source

Anybody knows where is it exactly that the `++` operator is applied to the expression being evaluated in the awk source ?

I am trying to dig deeper into the way the `++` (specifically) works (or doesn't work) in awk.

Being able to read (and analyze) the source code where that happens would be quite informative and probably useful.

But not being an expert on source code I am finding it difficult to pinpoint the exact lines that apply the operator to an expression.

Let's assume that we are talking about GNU awk, just because the source is open and I assume that [its source code is easier to get](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/) and review than other implementations. The current GNU awk version is 5.1.0, but any recent version should be quite similar. It should be helpful the description from any other (reasonable recent) implementation.

And, if that is relevant, assume that the awk script is simply:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ var=123 ; var++ ; print var }`
```

Which, of course, prints `124`, the question is how and where that gets to be so.

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/interpret.h?h=gawk-5.1-stable#n631?

Comment: That was fast !, thanks @muru

Comment: So, I assume that the increment is done on the line 640 (or 642) with the code: `t1->numbr += x;` (for the final value of an expression), or `*lhs = make_number(t1->numbr + x);` (for an intermediate result of a longer expression) where x is either +1.0 or -1.0. Which, I also assume, means that numbr (A pointer to the variable (`lvalue`) to increment?) is incremented. So: Should I also assume that any "side-effects" must be already applied when the execution reach the `;` at the end of either of those lines, Correct? @muru

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by side-effect here? Is the increment the side-effect?

Comment: Ah, sorry, the link got erased in a comment edit. ["side-effects" as defined by the c language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221359/side-effects-in-c) and particularly the "side effect" of `++` that in C could be delayed until the next `;`. [A function or expression is said to have a side effect if it does anything that persists beyond the life of the function or expression itself.](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/increment-decrement-operators-and-side-effects/)

Comment: Ok, in that case, yes, the effects must be applied by the time `;` is reached. Looking at [`awkgram.y`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/awkgram.y?h=gawk-5.1-stable#n2169), it looks like post operations are added on to a list as they're encountered. So, it doesn't seem to *wait* until the `;` to apply them, though. The manual says this is [implementation defined](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-sidebar-14).

Comment: Hmm. you lost me with the awkgram.y reference, sorry. Yes, the manual describes a complex use of a variable **several times**, yes, complex use might generate several results. However, in the code on this question, the awk script needs to execute a simple `x++`, not a double `++x + x++` or some other example. Should we accept the manual quote: "lvalue++ Increment lvalue, returning the old value of lvalue as the value of the expression.": increment first, return the non-incremented value for the rest of the expression?

Comment: Scratch my previous deleted comment, yes it seems you can take that quote as is.

Comment: Thanks @muru. Could you make it an answer, if you've got the time, of course!. :-)